# Recording the inputs of a command and producing a list of them later on

Tags: macros

I have some macros I use a lot, mostly just for my digital note keeping. Because of the nature of these macros, I could use a specific versions of these. For example I mention some file names throughout a document such as `\workdocument` which assigns them a specific url, and I would like to have a list of these files at the end of the document which I can just use to copy paste into some unix terminal tool. I could parse the file with a programming language to get these, but with multiple includes it isn't something I prefer.

The contents of these commands aren't references as one would semantically understand it, so I would like to avoid using bibtex.

If this can be accomplished with a feature that only exists in any of lualatex/xelatex/pdflatex, that is fine by me.

My tex file, in the simplest sense, looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\newcommand*\thingofnote[1]{#1} % Somehow add the input to an 'array' to be printed at the end as well?
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

A thing of note is \thingofnote{x}, while another thing of note is \thingofnote{y}.

\section{Section B}

One must not forget about \thingofnote{z}.

\section{All The Things}

% Here, create a list of all the things of note previously included in the document.
% Even this output would be acceptable, as long as it is not done manually:
% xyz

\end{document}
```

In the real document there are more commands and multiple includes.

This produces,
[image: In simplest terms, the file I have]

I would like to produce a version of,
[image: The file I would rather have]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See chapter 15 of the KOMA documentation which shows how to make new lists of things. The `tocloft` package can do this too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Dr. Seuss lovers, this approach will actually create macros `\thing1` and `\thing2`! (in `\csname` form, of course)

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{things}
\newcommand*\thingofnote[1]{#1%
  \stepcounter{things}\expandafter\gdef\csname thing\thethings\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand\listthings{%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \foreach\z in{1,...,\thethings}{\item \csname thing\z\endcsname}
  \end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

A thing of note is \thingofnote{x}, while another thing of note is \thingofnote{y}.

\section{Section B}

One must not forget about \thingofnote{z}.

\section{All The Things}

\listthings

\end{document}
```

[image]

The approach can be generalized to multi-paragraph things of note as follows:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{things}
\newcommand\thingofnote[1]{#1%
  \stepcounter{things}\expandafter\gdef\csname thing\thethings\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand\listthings{%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \foreach\z in{1,...,\thethings}{\item \csname thing\z\endcsname}
  \end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

A thing of note is \thingofnote{x

and new paragraph of more x}, while another thing of note is \thingofnote{y}.

\section{Section B}

One must not forget about \thingofnote{z}.

\section{All The Things}

\listthings

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just nitpicking: You don't need to use `\long\gdef` for `\thing<n>` (of course it doesn't hurt either :-) because the `\par` will be in the definition. Non-`\long` commands only trap `\par` when they appear in the argument. Also the `\expandafter` before `\long` can be dropped; TeX will remember prefixes until the first unexpandable token is found, so `\expandafter` is ok.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for that wisdom.  I learned something new!

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I am going to mark this as the answer since I have to choose one of them, but I probably will use similar code to both of these solutions in my documents over time. This seems easier to expand upon, although the etoolbox solution looks simpler for documents that I was already using the etoolbox package on. Thanks again, these help a lot.

Comment: I've tried to use this approach for slides with Beamer. It works until you use overlays. Then, the items get added multiple times :-/ I guess it's possible to work that somehow.

Comment: @FrederickNord I am sorry, but I have very little experience with beamer overlays, so I am not really one who can assist on that variation of the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Using `etoolbox`'s `\docsvlist`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\mylistofstuff{}
\newcommand*\thingofnote[1]{%
  \gappto\mylistofstuff{,{#1}}% Add to list
  #1}% write on paper
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

A thing of note is \thingofnote{x}, while another thing of note is \thingofnote{y}.

\section{Section B}

One must not forget about \thingofnote{z}.

\section{All The Things}

\begin{enumerate}
  \def\do#1{\item #1}
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\mylistofstuff}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```